# Can "num_online_cpus()" return different values in the same run?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

The name is suggesting it. If there are online cpus, are there offline cpus? can a offline cpu become online and vice versa?

Thanks in advance.
R.g.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- some architectures support "hot-pluggable CPUs":

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt

Hardware that actually supports this is rare as hen's teeth, though.

Comment: Note that as the documentation says, CPUs are offlined and onlined when an SMP system goes through suspend/resume, which is far more common.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that online in this context means "available for scheduling" and based on what i read in `include/linux/cpumask.h` where `num_online_cpus()` is defined. i'd think it would be possible for it to return different values at different times but in any stable system i don't think it would commonly do so.